# How to handle when Lookup defaultFieldValues parameters for e.force:createRecord are null

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, lightning-design-system

If the record has the **RecentAccount__c** lookup field populated then the new record creation modal pops up perfectly without error. Otherwise, if the record does not have the field populated it throws an error.

How to handle lookup fields that are null using force:createRecord? Is this a limitation? I would like for the new record creation modal to pop up simply with the lookup not populated if the field was null.

```
init : function(component, event, helper) {
   var createRegionTaskEvent = $A.get("e.force:createRecord");
   createRegionTaskEvent.setParams({
      "entityApiName": "Task",
      "defaultFieldValues": {
      "RecentAccount__c" : component.get("v.recordFields.RecentAccount__c") //could be null
 }
});
createRegionTaskEvent.fire() ;

$A.get("e.force:closeQuickAction").fire();
}
```

Comment: This is definitely not a limitation. where you have defined recordFields attribute? Can you add more detail on it?

Comment: What error is it throwing?

Comment: The error is the following "Looks like there's a problem.

Unfortunately, there was a problem. Please try again. If the problem continues, get in touch with your administrator with the error ID shown here and any other related details.
Error ID: 876852389-91738 (-799878288)" @Eric  Additionally I found this link.. https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000001Yo8yQAC

Comment: @ebar Oh my. Says it is fixed everywhere if you are on spring 20. Maybe they are wrong :(

Comment: It looks like so :( Verified the API is 48, that would be spring 20 correct?@Eric